# how to run python with args in python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a program in Python that scan files and then insert it into the command
when i try to run "python submit.py path/arg" i get an error. 
i tried many commands without success (os.system,os.Popen,subprocess.call,exec)
Thanks in advance

this is my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import glob
import subprocess
import commands
import time
import threading

exe = []
os.chdir("/home/malwares")
exe = glob.glob('*.exe')
exe1 = ''.join(exe)
exe1 = exe1.replace("']", "")
exe1 = exe1.replace("['", "")
os.chdir("/home/utils/")

//here i tried to run python script with args
subprocess.call(["python", "submit.py", "/home/malwares",exe1])
```

Comment: why do you call a subprocess for a python script? why not importing it and calling the function directly ?

Comment: 1. What do you mean? 
5. It does not matter errors, that probably function I use does not match.

Comment: OP: the `1` and `5` you see are people voting up the question, not the poster. @heinst was the 5 (tagged here for courtesy). The error most certainly DOES matter, since it pinpoints where the problem lies. njzk2 is asking why you're invoking a separate instance of Python to run `submit.py` instead of importing the module into this code and running it directly, which would be better, harder to screw up, conversely easier to debug, and cleaner to boot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by your calls to `str.replace`. Why would you have a filename with `[']` in it? But okay, fair enough, let's at least do it right then....

```
os.chdir('/home/malwares')
exe = glob.glob('*.exe') # no need to initialize this first.
exe_str = ''.join(exe) # name it a little more descriptively than exe1
trans_table = str.maketrans('', '', "[']")
exe_str = exe_str.translate(trans_table)
# this is probably faster than
# ''.join( [filename.translate(trans_table) for filename in glob.glob('*.exe')] )
# but you may want to profile it

subprocess.call( ['python', 'submit.py', '/home/malwares', exe_str] )
# is this REALLY what you want??? This will do:
# >> python submit.py /home/malwares FILEONE.exeFILETWO.exeFILETHREE.exe
# maybe you should have used ' '.join(exe) instead?
```

Comment: Thanks for the help 
I was going to subprocess.call( ['python', 'submit.py', '/home/malwares/', exe_str] ) To run the file with another python script (submit.py)

Comment: @user3532344 yes, that much is clear, it's just the REST of it that's murky :).